# What is the role of DC bit in GDT?

Tags: protected-mode, gdt

this is my code :

```
...
data_seg equ os_data-gdt_start
code_seg equ os_code-gdt_start
...
jmp code_seg:pm_start
[BITS 32]
pm_start:        
mov ax,data_seg
mov ds,ax
mov word [ds:0xb8000],0xC341
```

it work correctly when dc bit (Third bit of Access byte) in the gdt is zero.
I want to know why not work when it is 1?

I know that dc bit is Direction bit of data selectors , and when it's 0 , the segment grows up and when it's 1 the segment grows down. but not know what is the meaning of grows up and grows down exactly. grows up and grows down means to me when I want to use the stack.( ESP++ and ESP-- )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DC bit is name by osdev.org, by Intel´s manual it's expansion-direction. Number can go only in two directions: it can increase or decrease. DC bit is the thing that plays with it.

> If the size of a stack segment needs to be dynamically, the stack segment can be an expand-down data segment (**expansion-direction** flag is set). *Dynamically changing segment limit causes stack space to be added to the bottom of the stack*.

Comment: thank you, i always thought it was to control the direction towards which the stack grows loll, doesn't make sense ik